# GCloud ssh cannot connect when called

Tags: go, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-iap, identity-aware-proxy

I have testing code in Go, which sets up a state on a Compute Engine Instance (and don't want to expose the ports).
Since there seems to be no easy way of doing this in Golang directly, I utilize `gcloud`:

```golang
func TestMe(t *testing.T) {
  cmd := exec.Command("gcloud", "compute", "ssh", "--project", "foo", "--tunnel-through-iap", "--zone", "europe-west1-z", "bar", `--ssh-flag="-T"`, "--", "echo WOW")
  cmd.Env = os.Environ()
  out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
  println(string(out))
  t.Fatal(err)
}
```

When running `go test`, `cmd` outputs:

```
bash: myuser@compute.123456789: command not found
```

The compute instance is correct - but something fails when trying to access the compute instance. The same gcloud command works in bash (even for non-interactive). I assume there is something different in the Golang environment.

Comment: Can you show the code that fails? The `TestMe` body does not seem to be complete. Where is the code that outputs the error? And please, do include the code immediately preceding the line that prints the error.

Comment: The question is whether gcloud does produce such a script/binary implicitly. I vaguely remember having had a similar error in the past - but not what caused it.

Comment: Removing `--ssh-flag="-T"` seems to make it work. Both `-T` and `-t` fail?

Comment: Have you tried `"--ssh-flag='-T'"`? Just curious if it doesn't have something to do with how the shell treats double quoted strings.

Comment: `"--ssh-flag='-T'"` fails too

Comment: Try `"--ssh-flag", "-T"`

Comment: or `"--ssh-flag=-T"`, you are not executing a shell, so you don't need to put in quotes for the shell to remove.

Comment: @abergmeier Posted an answer, Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

There is a small correction  in the code.

corrected code:

```
func TestMe(t *testing.T)
 {
 cmd := exec.Command("gcloud", "compute", "ssh", "--project", "foo", "--tunnel-through-iap", "--zone", "europe-west1-z", "bar", "--ssh-flag=-T", "--", "echo WOW") 
cmd.Env = os.Environ()
 out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput() 
println(string(out)) 
t.Fatal(err) 
}
```

For more information related to troubleshooting ssh issues you can refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh).